# Android video view not playing in Paused state when seek bar is moved

Tags: android, android-videoview, seekbar

I am struggling with the issue that I have an video file to play. I have used video view to play the videos the implemented seek bar to seek to various positions as per the user requirements.

My seek bar is working perfectly while the video is playing. It seeks to respective position. But in paused state I don't get the same result.

here is my for seek bar

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {

                if (fromUser) {
                    // this is when actually seekbar has been seeked to a new
                    // position
                    video_view.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The problem is seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); So put it in Your AudioControl() Method..... You dont set oncheckchangedlistner to your seekbar....

Comment: I have put in in onStart() where I load the video and play

Comment: Did not get "Your AudioControl() Method"

Comment: please give answer i have the same problem